# Trying to print names in alphabetical order, error message says my program has an infinite loop

Tags: infinite-loop

[image]

I am a beginner and don't understand how to not produce an infinite loop in this context. The code is Python. I do not believe I am expected to produce code that automatically put the names in alphabetical order, rather its just to get comfortable printing characters.

Answer (score 1):

Put all of the names in an array first, then sort, then print.

```
names = ['Simeoni', 'Juhani',...]
names.sort()

print(names)
```

Comment: Did it work? If it did, feel free to accept the answer. Otherwise I'll give it another swing :)